# Почему Блаженный

Tags: этимология

Так почему Августина назвали "Блаженный"?

Answer (score 1):

На эту тему было целое исследование: 
 russ.hashcode.ru/research/19095/этимология-почему-блаженный-августин-имеет-такой-эпитет

Если кратко,то Блаженный = святой,католики его так и называют Святой Августин, Учитель Церкви.

Святой, потому что деяния его велики: Сорок три года жизни Августина после принятия им христианства считаются в богословской традиции образцом христианского образа жизни и служения. Он считается автором устава, которым руководствуются ряд монашеских орденов католической церкви: орден каноников-обсервантов св. А. (августинцы-каноники) и орден отшельников св. А. (августинские братья, из которых вышел Лютер и к которому принадлежал Г.Мендель), а также ассумпционисты (с середины 19 в.) и ряд женских монашеских конгрегаций августинок. Литературное наследие А. поистине необъятно:наиболее значительными произведениями А., оказавшими влияние не только на формирование христианского религиозного канона, но и на эволюцию европейской культуры в целом, являются "Исповедь" (400) и "О граде Божьем" (413-426). Учение А. сыграло значительную роль  в развитии христианской теологии,. оказало огромное влияние на формирование христианского богословского канона, его авторитет в вопросах теологии и философии был непререкаем. Экзистенциально-психологическая интерпретация Троицы, предложенная А., задала мощный импульс развития эмоционально-психологической составляющей христианства. Развил учение о предопределении. Автор произведений: "Против академиков", "О блаженной жизни", "О бессмертии души", "Об учителе", "О свободе воли" и др.

Comment: Конкретно там ничего не написано, а мне нужно кратко